# Проверка на существование информации массива в цикле

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Имеется такой php код:

`<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
}
?>`

Каким образом можно проверить существование $row['text']? Пробовал таким образом:

`<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  if(isset($row['text'])){
    echo $row['text']."<br>";
  }
  else{
    echo "Массив пуст";
  }
}
?>`

Но не помогло. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а, просто if (!$row['text']) или вот так:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news") or die ("Error #63678837");
if (mysql_num_rows($sql)){
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   // echo $row[]
  }
} else {
  echo 'Прости, но статей в БД нет :( ';
}
```

**[mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-num-rows.php)** — Возвращает количество рядов результата запроса

Comment: Работает второй способ, спасибо :)